Jenkins ssh agent ssh connection closed by remote
I have a Jenkins instance run on Podman engine. I setup Jenkins use cloud node to do task. But I get issue when master Jenkins create new ssh-agent after ssh connection. The Jenkins image and ssh-agent image are defualt don't add anything.
I use the same key and use ssh manually to connect agent I get below message.
I use same image file run on CentOS and use Docker engine, it is working. I am not sure is OS issue or engine issue.
OS Kernel: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) 3.10.0-1160.114.2.el7.x86_64
Docker Client version: 1.13.1
Docker Client API version: 1.26
Docker Server version: 1.13.1
Docker Server API version: 1.26


OS Kernel: Rocky Linux release 9.2 (Blue Onyx) 5.14.0-284.30.1.el9_2.x86_64
Podman version: 4.9.4-rhel


Jenkins version: 2.387.1-jdk11
ssh-agent: 5.5.0-jdk17

Error message from Jenkins
SSHLauncher{host='dockerhost', port=38253, credentialsId='InstanceIdentity', jvmOptions='', javaPath='', prefixStartSlaveCmd='', suffixStartSlaveCmd='', launchTimeoutSeconds=60, maxNumRetries=30, retryWaitTime=2, sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.NonVerifyingKeyVerificationStrategy, tcpNoDelay=true, trackCredentials=true}
[06/21/24 22:01:52] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to dockerhost:38253.
[06/21/24 22:01:52] [SSH] WARNING: SSH Host Keys are not being verified. Man-in-the-middle attacks may be possible against this connection.
[06/21/24 22:01:52] [SSH] Authentication successful.
SSH connection reports a garbage before a command execution.
Check your .bashrc, .profile, and so on to make sure it is quiet.
The received junk text is as follows:
Linux 79f33cfe5805 5.14.0-284.30.1.el9_2.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Sep 16 09:55:41 UTC 2023 x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.

null
[06/21/24 22:01:52] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[06/21/24 22:01:52] [SSH] Connection closed.

Debug message from ssh command
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 4/5/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to dockerhost closed by remote host.
Connection to dockerhost closed.
Transferred: sent 2804, received 2420 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 59467.1, received 51323.3
debug1: Exit status -1

